# DataGridView disable vertical resize of the header

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView for which I have disabled all resizing successfully. Except the vertical resize of the column headers, as I can't find a way to do that.. What's the property to change?

```
 class TransactionOverView : DataGridView {
        public TransactionOverView() {
            this.ClientSize = new Size(1008,720);
            this.AllowDrop = false;
            this.Columns.Add("nimetusColumn","Nimetus");
            this.Columns.Add("kogusColumn", "Kogus");
            this.Columns.Add("hindColumn", "Hind");
            this.Rows.Add("Toode 1","1","10.00 €");
            this.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            this.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            this.MultiSelect = false;
            this.ReadOnly = true;
            this.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            this.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in this.Columns)
            {
                column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent changing the height of column headers by setting `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode` to `DisableResizing` or `AutoSize`:

- If you set it to `DisableResizing`, the height of headers can be controlled by `ColumnHeadersHeight`.
- If you set it to `AutoSize`, the height of headers will be set based on the font and width of headers.

> [`ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersheightsizemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the height of the column
>   headers is adjustable and whether it can be adjusted by the user or is
>   automatically adjusted to fit the contents of the headers.